# How to Change Default Bootstrap Fluid Grid 12 Column Gutter Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I am looking to know if there is any **simple** solution known to change the gutter with on the **fluid** default 12 grid bootstrap system (2.3.0).

I am not familiar with LESS but if that is the answer, please also describe how to could be changed.  The same with Sass.

Please note that it is perfectly acceptable to change the gutter width, **by half** or **one fourth**, for example if that may make things simpler.

The following goals must be met:

1. Must be able to update bootstrap in the future.  This means not editing the actual bootstrap files.
2. Functionality should remain for all other objects.
3. Must be simple.  Less than 10 lines of CSS.  For example, an added class or something.

I have searched throughout Stack Overflow and still have no idea how I may go about doing something like this.  To the best of my understanding, **downloading a customized Bootstrap only renders custom gutter widths for non-fluid grids**. I have coded my own fluid grid system before, so I understand the math, but I am worried there may be consequences and it would be helpful if any known issues on class overrides could be shared.

I promise to give credit where it is due.

UPDATE:

Changing the less variables as described in Yoda's answer is the way to go.  Does anyone have any experience changing these less variables?  For example, I believe the variables that have to be changed are the following:

```
// Fluid grid
// -------------------------
@fluidGridColumnWidth:    percentage(@gridColumnWidth/@gridRowWidth);
@fluidGridGutterWidth:    percentage(@gridGutterWidth/@gridRowWidth);

// 1200px min
@fluidGridColumnWidth1200:     percentage(@gridColumnWidth1200/@gridRowWidth1200);
@fluidGridGutterWidth1200:     percentage(@gridGutterWidth1200/@gridRowWidth1200);

// 768px-979px
@fluidGridColumnWidth768:      percentage(@gridColumnWidth768/@gridRowWidth768);
@fluidGridGutterWidth768:      percentage(@gridGutterWidth768/@gridRowWidth768);
```

How does one go about changing something like this? Perhaps:

```
@fluidGridGutterWidth768:      percentage(1.5);
```

If anyone has done this before, I would appreciate a shove in the right direction.

Comment: If you have an answer, please either edit into the existing accepted answer; or write your own answer. Answers should not be placed in the question (that's why they're called questions).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use the Customizable download that Twitter Bootstrap provides. Change the @fluidGridGutterWidth variable to suit your needs in the form. [Download the less files from here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap). You can access the variable.less file from the github bootstrap project and then change this piece of code:

```
    // Fluid grid
// -------------------------
@fluidGridColumnWidth:    percentage(@gridColumnWidth/@gridRowWidth);
@fluidGridGutterWidth:    percentage(@gridGutterWidth/@gridRowWidth); // <= this one
```

I thought you had access to less files at first, then I realized you are using the customized gui on the website. Just download the less files, and make your changes. Then compile the less files to give you a css file or use less for development. You can use css or min.css for deployment.

Comment: Describe what you mean.  FYI, the link is dead.  I have not found any @fluidGridGutterWidth variable on bootstrap's customizations.

Comment: Only static gutter width variables for each media query.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for now, and as soon as I get this working, I'm going to give you a check mark.  Thank you.

Comment: It should work it depends what you are using in percentage() cause as you can see you have the source-code now, whatever compiles to a css file is your logic

Comment: I do have the less files, but it doesn't seem intuitive.  Perhaps you could point me in the right direction to begin.  For example, what is something that I would change here, forgetting about the math:  fluidGridGutterWidth1200: percentage(gridGutterWidth1200/gridRowWidth1200);  Do I make it fluidGridGutterWidth1200: percentage(1.5)?   I took out the at symbols due to comment restrictions.

Comment: Those values depends on the width of a column and width of a gutter between those columns that you want to have for your page. As you might have seen they are defining those variables in three different resolutions. Refer to your design  how you would like your column and gutter widths to be as everything depends on that.

Comment: Let's say, perhaps, you want each column to be 7.5%.  That would make margins 0.90909%.  How would you implement this?

Comment: fluidGridColumnWidth1200:  percentage(7.5);
fluidGridGutterWidth1200:  percentage(0.90909);   Like this?

Comment: I gave you the answer since you did answer my main question.  The details I believe I will figure out eventually.  If I get stuck again, I'll make another question.  Thank you for your help.  If I do fully figure it out, I will update the full details in my question for future users.

Comment: how do you compile the less files into the two main CSS files?

Comment: @streetlight there are 2 ways to do it either clientside or server side compilation of less to css. for development purpose you can go for client-side (not good for performance, page load will take time coz of the compilation process) but its good setup the environment of compilation server side. http://lesscss.org/#usage is for client-side. I use dotless compiler for my asp.net projects to compiles on server side http://www.dotlesscss.org/.

Comment: I fixed the broken link.

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be over thinking it. The problem with changing the LESS variables is that it will change it for all gutters. So if I like the 15px gutter for arranging the over all layout but want the gutter to be 5px for a form inside that grid it won't work.

Just create 2 css classes to override the areas you want to change the gutter.

Apply this at the "row" level.

```
.row-5-gutter{
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

Apply this at the "column" level.

```
.col-5-gutter{
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tg7Ey/

Comment: This seems to be the only CSS-only solution that's really working for the scenarios I'm testing.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a simple solution for this problem, too. My goal was to use simple CSS, not LESS. This answer as like any other i found, based on compiling LESS or using the online compiler of bootstrap. So i tried to find my own solution.

Reading the documentation you will find the following about the gutter-width: Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.

Based on this i tried the following:

```
.container {padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;}
.row {margin-left:-1px;margin-right:-1px;}
.row > div {padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;}
```

From now the gutter width was only 2 pixel. My next problem was, that my intended width was an odd number. My solution was to remove the paddings and margins on the left and put them completely on the right:

```
.container {padding-left:0;padding-right:5px;}
.row {margin-left:0;margin-right:-5px;}
.row > div {padding-left:0;padding-right:5px;}
```

Now i have a 5 pixel gutter width.

I did not tested this in all possible scenarios you can use bootstrap. Especially you have to  pay attention to use only column-div's inside a row-div inside a container-div. But in my case it was a very effective solution without touching the origin source code of bootstrap or using a LESS compiler.

Comment: What boostrap version are you using? Are you aware of the new version found at http://getbootstrap.com/ ?

Comment: I did use the version 3.0.2