# Setting the viewport meta tag to 1300?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I'm trying to fix some pages on my web design and ran into an issue where the sidebar banner ads that look fine on my regular desktop browser seemed to display "off the screen" on the iPhone and Android devices.  The issue seemed to go away by setting the viewport meta tag to a higher value (e.g. 1300).  While no side-effects have been found yet I was curious if setting the tag to that high a value was indicative of a bigger design issue?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1300" />
```

Comment: What do you mean "setting the viewport meta tag to a higher value?"  Please post your exact viewport meta tag.

Comment: I added it to the question.  Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Since if you are viewing your site on a mobile device, for example, your website will be tiny and unviewable.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1300" />
```

What your meta tag does is to say to the browser,

> "No matter the width of the screen this website is on (viewport width)
>   render it as though it were a 1300px wide screen."

What that will do is "zoom out" if your viewport is less than 1300px and "zoom in" if the viewport is greater than 1300px.

Now, it sounds to me that if you are using this to fix your layout, you have bigger problems.  I highly recommend you to look into bootstrap as a way to make your layout responsive.  Bootstrap is a library of css files that you add to your site to do quite a few things, one of which is to create a fluid, responsive grid system.

I recommend starting [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) to learn about bootstrap and what it can do and then google search some articles.  Everyone loves it! Trust me, once you realize how simple it can make your life, you will love it too.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really "fixing" a layout with the viewport but rather trying to get the entire screen shown on the phone.  I realize now that not having a responsive design where the information is properly zoomed is a mistake, however, I'm not sure how easy a fix it will be given where I am in development.  Have you had any experience "bootstrapping" an existing site?

Comment: Yes.  It is actually *made* for making an existing site responsive.

Comment: Mark this question as answered.  Start a new question with an actual example of your html structure and ask for pointers in the right direction in converting existing site into responsive bootstrap. I will write my own view of what I've done in the past and I'm sure others will chime in too.

Comment: What I am working on now is changing the Bootstrap Less variables to change the "fluid gutter width" which is the space between the columns.  As soon as I get it working, I will post my findings on my question.  Be sure to check it out when you get to that point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823742/how-to-change-default-bootstrap-fluid-grid-12-column-gutter-width